# jQuery toggleClass on specific class

Tags: jquery, toggleclass

I've made this jQuery code that toggles class to open and close.
but when I click on the Dashboard navigator it's also affecting the other classes

[Here is my sample code.](http://jsfiddle.net/efAZU/7/)

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('ul.nav li a#mainnav').click(function(){
        $('ul.nav li ul').toggleClass('opened');
    });
});
```

CSS:

```
div#wrapper div#main_sidebar ul.nav li ul.closed{
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
div#wrapper div#main_sidebar ul.nav li ul.opened{
    height: auto;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="main_wrapper">
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="main_sidebar">
            <ul class="nav">
                <li>
                    <a id="mainnav">Dashboard</a>
                    <ul class="closed opened">
                        <li><a href="#">Menu Manager</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Script Pages</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Plugin Manager</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">User Manager</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a id="mainnav">Settings</a>
                    <ul class="closed">
                        <li><a href="#">Post settings</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">User settings</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Permalink Structure</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a>Edit</a>
                    <ul id="main_nav" class="closed">
                        <li><a href="#">Edit Posts</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Edit Pages</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Edit Links</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Edit Menu Items</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to toggle only the specific list, use [`next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/) or [`siblings("ul")`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/):

```
$("#mainnav").click(function() {
    $(this).next().toggleClass("opened");
});​
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/efAZU/10/

Comment: how about if I would like to give it a slide effect? is it possible?

Comment: @KevinSteveManingo No problem, just use `slideToggle`: http://jsfiddle.net/efAZU/16/.

Comment: can it start with the navigator to be close at first?

Answer (score 1):

Upon clicking the mainNav, you are toggling all of them with your selector, instead try something like this in your `click` function:

```
$(this).siblings('ul').toggleClass('opened');
```

If you want the slide effect, you can use [slideToggle()](https://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/) instead.

Comment: how about if I would like to give it a slide effect? is it possible?